# iOS - Decode nested JSON with dynamic key

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to decode a JSON that one of the keys changes:

```
[
{
    "id": "device:us-east-1",
    "serial": "eng031",
    "account": "9340370e",
    "name": "moti123",
    "tags": {
        "group": [
            "office"
        ]
    },
    "isAttached": true,
    "isShared": false
},
{
    "id": "lambda:device:us-east-1",
    "serial": "106",
    "account": "9340370e",
    "name": "roei106 ",
    "tags": {
        "comment": [
            "Iron Maiden "
        ]
    },
    "isAttached": true,
    "isShared": false
}
]
```

As you can see the tags has a nested JSON with different keys in these example: ***group*** and ***comment***.

What I did before is pretty simple.
I had these structs:

```
public struct Device: Decodable {
  public init() {}

  public var id: String = ""
  public var serial: String = ""
  public var account: String = ""
  public var name: String = ""
  public var isAttached: Bool?
  public var isShared: Bool?
  public var tags: Tags?
 }

public struct Tags: Decodable {
  public init() {}

  public var comment: [String] = [""]
 }
```

And I used to parse them as follow:

```
   func getDevices(data: Data) -> [Device] {
    var devices = [Device]()

    do {
        let parsedModel = try JSONDecoder().decode([Device].self, from: data)
        devices = parsedModel
        print(parsedModel)
    } catch let error{
        print(error)
    }
    return devices
}
```

It all have worked fine until the key in the tags changed.
Is there any way to know what is the key and change it inside the tag struct?

Comment: Is it important for you to keep the difference between "comment" and "group"? Or you just want the array value?

Comment: @Larme it is not important

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see Tags contains a Dictionary, that have String as key and Array of string as value.

So you can modify

```
public struct Tags: Decodable {
  public init() {}

  public var contents: [String:[String]]?
 }
```

Comment: Did it like so:
[String:[String]] = ["":[""]]

Comment: Or you could use it as: `contents = [String:[String]]()`

Answer (score 0):

I recomend use this struct

```
typealias Scenarios = [Scenario]

struct YourJsonName: Codable {
    let id, serial, account, name: String
    let tags: Tags
    let isAttached, isShared: Bool
}

struct Tags: Codable {
    let group, comment: [String]?
}
```

If you need init:

```
 public struct Tags: Decodable {
    public init() {}
    public var  comment: [String]? = nil
    public var  group: [String]? = nil
 }
```

Comment: I need the public init() {} because this is a cocoapod

Comment: any more ideas ?

Comment: check updated answer.